# Submitting form using Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am working in ASP.net 2.0 application using C#

I have a .net user control, where I have a form.

Form validation is done by external agency using jquery. 
I am able to submit all the form, except one form where form is opening in lightbox.

Agency asked to submit this form using ajax call where alert message is shown. I am able to see alert message when button is clicked but form is not submitted

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('requestquote1_btnSubmit').onclick = function(e) {
    if (jlib.validate(e)) {
        alert('Validate PASSED - .NET control will handle the AJAX submission from here');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};​
</script>
```

Please help me how to submit the request using ajax call.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? What is the HTML involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit a form using jQuery with the `submit` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('requestquote1_btnSubmit').onclick = function(e) {
        if (jlib.validate(e)) {
            alert('Validate PASSED - .NET control will handle the AJAX submission from here');
            $('#formid').submit();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};​
</script>
```

Comment: When submitting the form like this ASP.net is throwing error below: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. 
Please suggest